# How do I set up a mySQL table structure for a business directory with many to many relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, many-to-many

I am trying to plan my table structure for a business directory where I will have multiple parent categories for multiple sub-categories and multiple business listings, all of which will require a many to many relationship.

eg.

**A Night Out**

Clubs and Societies
Public Houses
**Restaurants**
Taxis and Private Hire Vehicles
Theatres and Concert Halls
Wine Bars

**Restaurants**

Chinese / Oriental
Bistros
Fish and Chips
Indian
Italian
Public Houses
Seafood
Spanish

**Transport and Carriers**

Air Charter and Rental
Airlines
Car / Van Hire Self Drive
Courier and Distribution Services
Estate / Property Re-location Services
Freight Services and Agents
Haulage Contractors
Post Offices and Services
Re-location Services
Taxis and Private Hire Vehicles
Van Hire

As you can see, **Restaurants** is both a main category and a subcategory. Taxis and Private Hire Vehicles belongs to both **Transport and Carriers** and **A Night Out** and under all of these categories, on the lowest level, I will have the business listings. I will not be allowing businesses to submit their own listings but rather adding them myself upon request. A business listing can belong to a maximum of 6 categories.

I am struggling to find the best structure of tables for my database and would be very grateful for any suggestions. I am relatively new to php/mySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a category table which will contain a list of all possible categories/subcategories and then in your information table have it so that there is a CategoryID field as well as a SubCategoryID where you will either have NULL for the subcategory or the corresponding id.

---

You could also map it using a mapping table, that way you will be able to have as many categories / subcategories as you want.

```
Category Table ( CategoryId, CategoryName )
Business Table ( BusinessId, BusinessName )
Category Mapping Table ( BusinessId, CategoryId, IsCategory )
```

The IsCategory would be a BIT field so that you can mark any number of categories for a business as either a SubCategory (0) or a Category (1).

On the Category Mapping Table I would make the PRIMARY KEY ( BusinessId, CategoryId ) as well as make them FOREIGN KEYs to the Business / Category table respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What would happen where a category has multiple sub categories? I cannot have multiple Sub Category ID's in the one field. Would I have headings such as Sub_Cat_1, Sub_Cat_2 ... with NULL value entered in those fields for any that have no sub-categories and an ID if they do?

Comment: I'm editing my post for that now.  Shortly after I wrote that, I thought of that.

Comment: Just thinking how much work this will be when I have thousands of businesses. Would I have to go through and mark them all as a 0 or 1?

Comment: You could always write a script or an application to update it for you, like when you add in a new category / subcategory to a business at that time include whether or not it is a subcategory or category (i.e. set the bit).

Comment: That would work great for new businesses. Problem is I already have well over a thousand and around 100 different categories (broken down into main and sub-categories) that they can belong to. I guess i'm just gonna have to punch them all in :0( Thanks for your response judda.

Comment: Well, what was the table structure that the data was stored in originally, because you could probably use a quick script to import it into the new hierarchy table setting 1 / 0 for it.

Comment: The data has been supplied in a series of spreadsheets. Spreadsheet 1 is a list of all main categories (column headers) with the corresponding subcategories populating the columns. Subcategories of these subcategories have been supplied in separate spreadsheets (Each titled with it's parent category) Spreadsheet 2 contains all business data in separate rows for each business. I don't know if that makes any sense.

Comment: Then you should be able to import these two files into a temporary table and then just write a query that will be used to actually automatically insert the specific ones.

Comment: @judda: I really don't like this `IsCategory` bit field. And I can't see where the relationship between a category and a subcategory is going to be stored.

Comment: The `IsCategory` bit is only to allow you keep categories and subcategories together. It would go into the `CategoryMapping` table I believe?  Or you could add another mapping of sorts to say a parent category for each (businessid, categoryid) pair